# How to Add a Row in Dataframe which gives total and average for all column at the same time

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I Have a dataframe:

```
Part     Num1      Num2      Avg1      Avg2
A        10        15        5         3
B        20        10        5         7
C        20        25        10        15
```

In Required Output i want to add one row which give me total of `Num1` and `Num2` and Average for `Avg1` and `Avg2`.

Required Output:

```
Part     Num1      Num2      Avg1      Avg2
A        10        15        5         3
B        20        10        5         7
C        20        25        5         15
Total    50        50        5         8.33
```

Comment: I guess you can do that in tableu and excel.

Comment: Did you try something on your own?

Comment: Please share whatever you have tried till now.

Comment: `rbind(df[, -1], c(colSums(df[, 2:3]), colMeans(df[, 4:5])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`

```
rbind(df, c("Total", sum(df$Num1), sum(df$Num2), mean(df$Avg1), mean(df$Avg2))
```

Comment: `rbind(df[-1],c(colSums(df[,2:3],colMeans(df[,4:5])))`

Comment: @Onyambu It removed the first column `Part` from dataframe. and how can i do this for alternative columns. i.e sum for column 2,3,6 & 7 and Average for column 4,5,8 & 9. I have tried this `rbind(df[-1],c(colSums(df[,2,3,6,7],colMeans(df[,4,5,8,9])))` but it didn't work.

Comment: you need to use `c` function. ie `rbind(df[-1],c(colSums(df[,c(2,3,6,7)],colMeans(df[,c(4,5,8,9)])))`

Comment: You can add the part that was removes if you want. by `cbind` function

Comment: @Onyambu but in that case i wouldn't be able to give Name "Total" to last row and please suggest me how can i sum and average for alternative columns.

Comment: You can include `total`

Comment: I am sorry I did not get your question

Comment: @Onyambu Suppose i want to sum for column number 2,3,6,7 and menas for 4,5,8,9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165540/discussion-between-rahul-shah-and-onyambu).

Comment: That is exactly what I told you to do:`rbind(df[-1],c(colSums(df[,c(2,3,6,7)],colMeans(df[,c(4,5,8,9)])))`

Comment: @Onyambu I had already tried but not working properly it give me sum correct in column 2,3 but in mean for column 4,5 it give me sum of column 6,7.

Comment: But thats exactly what you want.. lookit should sum  columns 2,3,6,7. Thats what we have ie colSums(df[,c(2,3,6,7)])..if you need the mean, take thet column into the colMeans...and viceversa